# Special type of DMZ?

Tags: iptables, dhcp, nat, dd-wrt

So I have a standard modem-router setup all great to go, my Modem gives an IP Address from my provider via DHCP according to my Mac address. All is good.
However, I now want to expose a new virtual server to the internet. I already have multiple port forwards etc on my existing setup, and I don't want to try splitting ports between the two machines they're assigned to (i.e., I already port forwards 443 and 22 to one host, it seems nigh impossible to have it go to two different hosts inside the network because outside there is only one IP address).

I only need one machine set up this way, all the others are expected to use the DHCP server like normal.

What I envision is that the computer to be granted an external IP address will ask the DD-wrt roter for an IP address. Because its' MAC address is filtered to go to the outside, this traffic is forwarded on to the modem, which gets an IP from my provider and sends it on down the line to the computer.

I'm thinking this can be accomplished using some kind of iptables magic, but I'm not experienced enough to dabble.
Any hints?

Comment: What your thinking of doing is not possible

Comment: @Ramhound Any particular reason why not? This is basically configuring the router to be a man-in-the-middle for only a specific mac-address... :/

Comment: It short, it doesn't work that way.  You need a second external IP, which your isp may or may not make available at an additional cost (it depends on your class of connection, it's often NOT available for consumer grade connections where the isp's TOS prohibits operating a server on the connection.)  Beyond that this is what port forwarding is for.